# "Use of undefined constant..." error in Laravel

Tags: php, templates, laravel

I am a Laravel newbie. I want to pass the results of a database query to a view. I get an error message "Use of undefined constant tasks - assumed 'tasks'". What am I doing wrong?

My code is as follows:

```
class TasksController extends BaseController{
    public function index(){
        $tasks = Task::all();

        //return View::make(tasks.index, ['tasks' => $tasks]);
        return View::make(tasks.index, compact('tasks'));
    }
```

A snippet from my template page is shown below:

```
<body>
    <h1>All tasks!</h1>

    @foreach($tasks as $task)
        <li>{{ $task-title }} </li>
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
return View::make('tasks.index')->with(compact('tasks'));
```

also change:

```
<li>{{ $task-title }} </li>
```

to

```
<li>{{ $task->title }} </li>
```

should be like this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 return View::make(tasks.index, $tasks);
```

instead of

```
return View::make(tasks.index, compact('tasks'));
```